# How to avoid duplicate Id tags when working with Ajax in MVC

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi guys I was wondering if you could share some of the precautions, management techniques and methods that you use when working with Ajax or MVC functions like @Html.Action with respect to managing and avoiding duplicate `Ids` for Html tags?

Also if two tags have same Id how will the page be handled? I know it will affect some styling, javascript functions and form inputs but apart from that is there anything else that I need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for the HTML prefix as below.

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
   ...
   ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix="ActionName";
   return View();
}
```

so that your view will be rendered with unique Id's for the input types.